# Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to filter my DataView by date:

```
DataTable dt = GetTableData();
DataView dvEvents = dt.DefaultView;
dvEvents.RowFilter = "date > #" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "#";
```

But I'm getting this error:

> **Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.DateTime.**

I've also tried `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`, and I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried to duplicate your error, but the code worked fine. My table had a field named date that was of type System.DateTime. It was the only field in the datatable. I used your rowfilter verbatim. This leads me to believe your date field isn't really a DateTime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using string values you need to replace the `#` with `'`.

For example:

```
dvEvents.RowFilter = "date > '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "'";
```

See [this reference](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Comment: I also recommend using `DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "u")` to avoid problems with user culture settings.

Comment: Dai's suggestion is very useful.  The proper syntax is Datetime.Now.ToString("u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `date` is defined as a string. You have two options.

You can either make sure string is stored in `yyyyMMdd` format (so that sorting and filtering works properly) and filter such as:

```
 dvEvents.RowFilter = "date > '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'";
```

OR you can turn `date` into actual `DateTime` column and keep you current code

Answer (score 0):

If date coming from database, then you have to do a locale conversion before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and none of the already suggested resolutions worked. 
A work around was to use

```
DataTable dt = GetTableData();
DataView dvEvents = dt.DefaultView;
dvEvents.RowFilter = "date > '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY") + "'";
```

Hope this helps someone.